# Clearing *.kml files in Temporary Internet Files

Tags: c#

I want to clear all kml files in Temporary Internet Files. I tried recursive directory search but no kml files are found, although you can see kml files when you browse with windows explorer. In the actual directories of "Temporary Internet Files",like Content.IE5, there exists *.xml counterparts for these kml files. I also deleted them but windows explorer still shows the kml files.
I also tried some WinApi methods but I couldn't write the code I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Temporary Internet Files are handled similar to Recycle Bin files, i.e. there's an index file with meta data (such as file names) and files containing the actual contents. You might be able to use [`GetUrlCacheEntryInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384185%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get file informations, but I don't think there's any specific/easy way to clear all files excluding a specific sub set (without not damaging the cache files as you do by simply deleting files without updating meta data or iterating over all files in the cache).

Edit: I misunderstood you (I think; you just want to delete a specific set of files; not everything else). If you'd like to delete all *.kml files only, you might be able to do it:

- Find the cache entries with `FindFirstUrlCacheEntry` and `FindNextUrlCacheEntry).
- Use `DeleteUrlCacheEntry` to delete the entries you've found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used the code from [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/b5721e4f-6b58-465e-82eb-629613c7de4a](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxnetcom/thread/b5721e4f-6b58-465e-82eb-629613c7de4a)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache` path

```
        string tempPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache);

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo tempDir = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath );
        foreach (FileInfo file in tempDir.GetFiles("*.kml"))
        {
            file.Delete();
        }
```

You should also update the code to delete files in subdirectories as well.

Hopefully it will help.